# Event loop wrong order of execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, event-loop

I have this very simple Nodejs example to understand the event loop

```
setTimeout(function() {
   console.log("Timeout 1");
}, 0);

fs.readFile("test-file-empty.txt", () => {
   console.log("File 1");
});

setTimeout(function() {
   console.log("Timeout 2");
}, 100);

setImmediate(function() {
   console.log("Immediate 1");
});
```

This gives the following output

```
Timeout 1
Immediate 1
File 1
Timeout 2
```

From my understanding of the event loop, these should be the `ticks` or loops for the example above:

First tick:

```
Timeout 1
File 1
Immediate 1
```

Second tick:

```
Timeout 2
```

1) Please correct me if I'm wrong about the ticks number and components

2) Why the `setImmediate` callback is executing before the `fs.readFile` I/O callback even though `setImmediate` should run in the Check phase which follows the Poll phase (which handles the I/O callbacks)? Note: the text file is empty BTW so should just execute immediately

Comment: Have you tried reading a larger file? how does this change the outcome

Comment: @DanStarns yes the same behaviour with a 1 million line file. That's the expected behavior for a large file but for empty one I believe it should not

Comment: This execution is happening as it should be because it all executed based on the time delay of each execution.. You can try with ```async/await``` if you want right order.

Comment: @ManirajMurugan what is the delay with an empty file? It's callback should be just immediately so before the setimmediate (check) phase

Comment: Who knows what the additional overhead of `fs.readFile` is.  You can't guarantee async calls will execute in the order they are written without taking additional steps like nesting callbacks or async/await.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're wrong about the first tick showing you three logs. Each of `setTimeout` and `setImmediate` and the callback will schedule a separate task for the event loop to pick up. So you'd get one per tick. Moreover, if I'm not mistaken the `setImmediate` would go to the **micro**task queue, so it shouldn't happen at the same time as the `setTimeout` which schedules a **macro**task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in the book saying how long I/O operations should take. Imagine that the zero byte file was on a network drive. You'll still have to take into account the latency of the network, so in that case you might even see

```
Timeout 1
Immediate 1
Timeout 2
File 1
```

I changed your program to use `fs.stat` instead of `fs.readFile`. The `stat` operation should take an amount of time that's independent of the file size. In that case, on *my* machine, I see:

```
Timeout 1
File 1
Immediate 1
Timeout 2
```

... which goes to show that the file operation was completed on the next tick. But again, there's no guarantee that that happens. If the file's metadata is not in the cache, then the program still needs to wait for the kernel to fetch the metadata from disk, which is a relatively slow operation.

---

Interestingly, on occasion (maybe once every 10 tries) I would see this:

```
File 1
Immediate 1
Timeout 1
Timeout 2
```

Which means that `setTimeout(..., 0)` is actually not guaranteed to execute on the next tick.

Comment: "*Which means that `setTimeout(..., 0)` is actually not guaranteed to execute on the next tick.*" indeed, if there is a microtask scheduled, then it will go before the one done with `setTimeout`. In addition, you might simply have a different task that gets scheduled before this one.

Answer (score 0):

I find a clue from [nodejs official document](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/), they say:

> If the poll phase becomes idle and scripts have been queued with setImmediate(), the event loop may continue to the check phase rather than waiting.

Look at your codes, at the end line, you invoke `setImmediate`, so `Check phase` adds a callback into its queue.

When comes to the `Poll phase`, its queue is empty and `Check phase` queue is not empty, so event loop won't wait for `Poll phase`, just jump to the `Check phase`, log out 'Immediate 1'.

If you want to log 'File 1' before 'Immediate 1', I recommend you to refactor your codes:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
   console.log("Timeout 1");
}, 0);

fs.readFile("test-file-empty.txt", () => {
   console.log("File 1");

   // Just Put here
   setImmediate(function() {
      console.log("Immediate 1");
   });
});

setTimeout(function() {
   console.log("Timeout 2");
}, 100);
```

To tell the truth, event loop is very difficult to understand in details.There is an exception if you're able to read the node source code and figure out the internal **cpp/c** codes.For me, it's out of my imagination.

If someone knows internal reason based on c/cpp source codes of `nodejs`, welcome to comment, really appreciate!